# How to call a .Net 4.51 RESTFUL API from a 2.0 .net web form

Tags: webforms

I have some legacy applications that needs to call a new .net RESTFul API.  What I am not sure of is if I can call a 4.51 API from a 2.0 web form.

Answer (score 1):

For such a general question, I can give you a general answer.

Use [HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx) to make web requests to your REST API from your code behind, or make http requests from your javascript.

If you need to make requests to your REST API from your code behind, you will likely need [JSON.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) to serialize the data from json to a .net object.

[JSON.NET is available as a nuget package.](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/)